# Extracting graphs with 2 nodes using networkx and python

Tags: python, networkx

I have a networkx graph with many nodes and edges.  Some of the nodes share only one edge with another node.  How do I extract a list of the isolated 2 node graphs?

The table of data I am working with looks like this

```
>|Name1|Name2|distance|
>|----|----|----|
>|AAA|BBB|2.315544|
>|AAB|BBB|2.576293|
>|AAC|BBB|2.967239|
>|AAD|BBB|2.779942|
>|...|...|...|
```

The graph looks like this:

[image]

Alternatively, is there a way to generate a list of clusters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "clusters" are typically called components in network analysis.
In networkx, you can compute them using the function [`nx.connected_components`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.connected_components.html), which returns an iterator over components. Each component returned by the iterator simply a list of nodes.

```
import networkx as nx

g = nx.Graph()
... # add nodes & edges 
components = nx.connected_components(g)
for component in components:
    if len(components) == 2:
        # do something special with components of size 2
```

If you are only interested in the largest component (often called "giant component"), it is worth noting that you can then sort the components or find the largest group by post-processing this output as detailed in the documentation:

```
Generate a sorted list of connected components, largest first.

>>> G = nx.path_graph(4)
>>> nx.add_path(G, [10, 11, 12])
>>> [len(c) for c in sorted(nx.connected_components(G), key=len, reverse=True)]
[4, 3]

If you only want the largest connected component, it's more
efficient to use max instead of sort.

>>> largest_cc = max(nx.connected_components(G), key=len)
```

Comment: Thank you! This is not my area of expertise and I also appreciate you pointing out the right vocabulary.

Comment: Did you mean `nx.connected_components(g)`? It doesn't yield the connected components in order of size though...

Comment: @mozway It does with networkx version 2.5.1.

Comment: @Paul can you provide a link to the doc of `nx.components`? I'm unable to reproduce your code, for me its the module and not a callable. With `connected_components` on networkx 2.8.6 this yields the component in the found order, not by size: `list(nx.connected_components(nx.Graph([('A', 'B'), ('C', 'D'), ('D', 'E')])))` -> `[{'A', 'B'}, {'C', 'D', 'E'}]`

Comment: @mozway Sorry, I should have been more explicit. You were correct that the function is called `connected_components`. I was correct that the returned result is ordered (at least in the version I am working with).

Comment: Are you sure the behavior is documented/reliable? This is certainly not the case for the current version (does my above line yield `[{'C', 'D', 'E'}, {'A', 'B'}]` for you?). And I'm surprised it ever was as this would defeat the purpose of a generator. Sorting by size would require the components, then they should be pre-computed somehow…

Comment: @mozway Added the docstring for your reading pleasure.

Comment: OK, then as I said, it **does not** yield them in order, you **must sort them yourself** with `sorted` or `max` to get the max ;)

Comment: Yeah, you are. Patched it in my local version and forgot.

Comment: I edited your answer for clarity ;)